# More dry views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have a simple index page for `clients`. Client has 20 fields. I am displaying list of clients in a table. For this I have to write in my views something like:

```
- @clients.each do |client|
  %tr
   %td=client.name
   %td=client.email
   %td=client.address
   %td=client.phone etc...
```

I am just curious if I can do it something like

```
- @clients.each do |client|
  - client do
      %tr
       %td= name
       %td= email
       %td= address
       %td= phone etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do something like

```
- @clients.each do |client|
  - client.instance_eval do
      %tr
       %td= name
       %td= email
       %td= address
       %td= phone etc...
```